# same onclick function for multple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am working on a little gallery of images, and some of the pages have up to 100 images.  When you open the page you have small images, and when they are clicked a new higher resolution image is opened up, from a specific folder.  Is it possible to allow that the happen in one click function or a way to use a lot less code.  I just don't want to have to use several different onclick functions for each image, that would just take a lot of time.

Here is a look at my markup and javascript code

MarkUp

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

    <link href="../App_Themes/Gallery/Gallery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
<div id="images">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" CssClass="Image1" hspace="25" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery1_Small.jpg" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" CssClass="Image2" hspace="25" vspace="15" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery2_Small.jpg" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image3" CssClass="Image3" hspace="25" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery3_Small.jpg" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image4" CssClass="Image4" hspace="25" vspace ="15" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery4_Small.jpg" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image5" CssClass="Image5" hspace="25" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery5_Small.jpg" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image6" CssClass="Image6" hspace="25" vspace ="15" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery6_Small.jpg" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image7" CssClass="Image7" hspace="25" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery7_Small.jpg" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image8" CssClass="Image8" hspace="25" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery8_Small.jpg" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image9" CssClass="Image9" hspace="25" vspace="15" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery9_Small.jpg" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image10" CssClass="Image10" hspace="25" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery10_Small.jpg" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image11" CssClass="Image11" hspace="25" vspace="15" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery11_Small.jpg" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image12" CssClass="Image12" hspace="25" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery12_Small.jpg" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image13" CssClass="Image13" hspace="25" vspace="15" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery13_Small.jpg" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image14" CssClass="Image14" hspace="25" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery14_Small.jpg" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image15" CssClass="Image15" hspace="25" vspace="15" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery15_Small.jpg" />
   </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Javascript Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(".Image1").click(function () {
         $(".Image1").attr("src", function (index, currentSource) {
             return currentSource == "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery1_Big.jpg"
                 ? "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery1_Small.jpg"
                 : "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery1_Big.jpg";
         });    
         //$("#images:not(.Image1)").hide();
         //$('.Image1').appendTo('body');
         //$('.Image1').css("margin-left", "450px");
     });
     $(".Image2").click(function () {
         $(".Image2").attr("src", function (index, currentSource) {
             return currentSource == "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery2_Big.jpg"
                 ? "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery2_Small.jpg"
                 : "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery2_Big.jpg";
         });
     });
     $(".Image3").click(function () {
         $(".Image3").attr("src", function (index, currentSource) {
             return currentSource == "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery3_Big.jpg"
                 ? "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery3_Small.jpg"
                 : "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery3_Big.jpg";
         });
     });
     $(".Image4").click(function () {
         $(".Image4").attr("src", function (index, currentSource) {
             return currentSource == "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery4_Big.jpg"
                 ? "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery4_Small.jpg"
                 : "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery4_Big.jpg";
         });
     });
     $(".Image5").click(function () {
         $(".Image5").attr("src", function (index, currentSource) {
             return currentSource == "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery5_Big.jpg"
                 ? "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery5_Small.jpg"
                 : "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery5_Big.jpg";
         });
     });
     $(".Image6").click(function () {
         $(".Image6").attr("src", function (index, currentSource) {
             return currentSource == "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery6_Big.jpg"
                 ? "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery6_Small.jpg"
                 : "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery6_Big.jpg";
         });
     });
     $(".Image7").click(function () {
         $(".Image7").attr("src", function (index, currentSource) {
             return currentSource == "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery7_Big.jpg"
                 ? "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery7_Small.jpg"
                 : "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery7_Big.jpg";
         });
     });
     $(".Image8").click(function () {
         $(".Image8").attr("src", function (index, currentSource) {
             return currentSource == "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery8_Big.jpg"
                 ? "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery8_Small.jpg"
                 : "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery8_Big.jpg";
         });
     });
     $(".Image9").click(function () {
         $(".Image9").attr("src", function (index, currentSource) {
             return currentSource == "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery9_Big.jpg"
                 ? "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery9_Small.jpg"
                 : "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery9_Big.jpg";
         });
     });
     $(".Image10").click(function () {
         $(".Image10").attr("src", function (index, currentSource) {
             return currentSource == "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery10_Big.jpg"
                 ? "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery10_Small.jpg"
                 : "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery10_Big.jpg";
         });
     });
     $(".Image11").click(function () {
         $(".Image11").attr("src", function (index, currentSource) {
             return currentSource == "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery11_Big.jpg"
                 ? "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery11_Small.jpg"
                 : "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery11_Big.jpg";
         });
     });
     $(".Image12").click(function () {
         $(".Image12").attr("src", function (index, currentSource) {
             return currentSource == "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery12_Big.jpg"
                 ? "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery12_Small.jpg"
                 : "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery12_Big.jpg";
         });
     });
     $(".Image13").click(function () {
         $(".Image13").attr("src", function (index, currentSource) {
             return currentSource == "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery13_Big.jpg"
                 ? "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery13_Small.jpg"
                 : "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery13_Big.jpg";
         });
     });
     $(".Image14").click(function () {
         $(".Image14").attr("src", function (index, currentSource) {
             return currentSource == "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery14_Big.jpg"
                 ? "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery14_Small.jpg"
                 : "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery14_Big.jpg";
         });
     });
     $(".Image15").click(function () {
         $(".Image15").attr("src", function (index, currentSource) {
             return currentSource == "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery15_Big.jpg"
                 ? "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery15_Small.jpg"
                 : "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery15_Big.jpg";
         });
     });
 </script>
```

Thank you as any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Couldn't you give them all the same class name? To my knowledge class names are meant to be reused for things like this.

Comment: Yes I actually was gonna do that, but then I realized it probably would work, because it wouldn't load the correct image for the specific image that was clicked, because each image has a different path name in the folder

Comment: You could use a combination of class and ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can simply change the `"Big.jpg"` and `"Small.jpg"` and directory names in a single event handler

Something like:

```
$('#images img').click(function(){
   $(this).attr('src', function(i, existSrc){
        if(existSrc.indexOf('Big.jpg') >-1){
             return existSrc.replace('Big.jpg','Small.jpg')
                            .replace('Big_Images','Small_Images');
        }else{
            return existSrc.replace('Small.jpg','Big.jpg');
                            .replace('Small_Images','Big_Images');
        }
   });       
});
```

Adding common classes and toggling a `big` class or similar on each one would also help simplify this further

Comment: Hey thank you for showing me an example.  As I do understand the code, but for some reason it just isn't working.  maybe missing something.  thanks

Comment: what happens? Have you inspected the live html in browser dev tools to see what new values are?

Comment: well it doesn't do anything the images don't change or anything

Comment: oh ok not it says it just cant find the file

Comment: and is the url what you expected? That's not extremely informative by itself

Comment: no I am trying to figure it out.  Its giving me the url ../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery1_Big.jpg

Comment: ../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery1_Big.jpg

Comment: the second one is the url its giving me instead of the first one posted

Comment: i see flaw in my concept...didn't notice the different directories for Big and Small...need to add another `replace()` for `Small_Images` and `Big_Images` also. can chain them together. See update and try that

Comment: Thank You so much it is Working

Answer (score 2):

1. Use common class for all images and set click listener to class.
2. Append index to your filename to get the mapped image.

See below example and implement accordingly. Here testImage is common class for all images.

```
$(".testImage").click(imageClick);

function imageClick(event) {
    $(event.target).attr("src", function (index, currentSource) {
        return currentSource == ($('.testImage').index(this) + 1) + ".png"
                 ? ($('.testImage').index(this) + 1) + "_small.png"
                 : ($('.testImage').index(this) + 1) + ".png";
    });
}
```

Comment: I guess I'm pretty new to javascript.  Can you show me an example please.  Thanks

Comment: @StephenBrown See above example and implement accordingly.

Comment: @StephenBrown You can also reduce your code by dynamically add the image tag based on number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you can reuse the event handler for all the images, this will significantly lower your memory consumption and increase your code maintainability.

Try something like this:

```
var images = /* an array holding all your img elements */    
var handler = function(event) {
        $(event.target).attr("src", function (index, currentSource) {
            var sn = event.target.id.match(/Image(\d+)/)[1];
            var small = "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Small_Images/Gallery" + sn + "_Small.jpg";
            var big = "../App_Themes/Gallery/HomeImages/Big_Images/Gallery" + sn + "_Big.jpg";
            return (currentSource === small 
            ? big
            : small);
        });
};

images.forEach(function(image) {
    image.click(handler);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for everyone's input